# How to hook into the Visual Studio IntelliSense completion keys to change when it triggers

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-2015, mef, visual-studio-extensions

Visual Studio 2015 does not have a way to only select IntelliSense when I press Enter or Tab anymore in C# for 2015. It's available for JavaScript but not C#.

I'm trying to create a MEF project and hook into the IntelliSense to change this behaviour for C# files. Just to get started, I tried to implement this sample plugin from Microsoft:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314.aspx

The sample compiles, but it does not work. Nothing in the code is triggered from the debugged IDE. The samples tells to start a new text file and press "a" to get demo IntelliSense, but it never trigger.

Here's the code project if anyone want to look into it:
http://ontime.zdata.no/donwload/ProperIntellisense.zip

Could someone guide me in the right direction here, the documentation in this area is very fluid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to press Ctrl+Alt+Space when inside the editor. That will toggle into the correct IntelliSense behaviour. Not a very easy thing to find, but it saved my day. They should probably give better information about this toggle feature, and make it more visible.. Still, it will not be remembered after closing the IDE, so you have to do it every time you start the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a supported way to use the APIs to customize this. The behavior you're looking to change falls under the [Roslyn project on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/) so you're more than welcome to file a bug there as feedback. You're also welcome to send a pull request, but at this point it's really tricky to make a change to the editor components of Roslyn and apply those to your locally installed Visual Studio. It's something we're working on fixing but it's not done yet.